# How to determine field-type for SOLR indexing?

Tags: java, php, sql, mysql, solr

I have two table fields in a MySQL table.
One is VARCHAR and is a "headline" for a classified (classifieds website).
The other is TEXT field which contains the "text" for the classified.

**Two Questions:** 
**How should I determine how to index these two fields?** (what field-type, what classes to use etc)

Currently I have an "ad_id" as a unique identifier for each ad, example "bmw_m3_82398292". 
**How can I make SOLR return this identifier whenever a 'query match' is found by SOLR?**
(The first part of the identifier is actually the headline fields content, the second part is a random number chosen)

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*1. Schema*

Your Solr schema is very much determined by your intended search behavior. In your schema.xml file, you'll see a bunch of choices like "text" and "string". They behave differently.

```
<fieldtype name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"     omitNorms="true"/>
```

The string field type is a literal string match. It would operate like `==` in a SQL statement.

```
<fieldtype name="text_ws"   class="solr.TextField"          positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

The text_ws field type does tokenization. However, a big difference in the `text` field is the filters for stop-words and delimiters and lower-casing. Notice how these filters are designated for both the Lucene index and the Solr query. So when searching a text field, it will adapt the query terms using these filters to help find a match.

```
<fieldtype name="text"      class="solr.TextField"  positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter ..... />
    <filter ..... />
    <filter ..... />
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

When indexing things like news stories, for example, you probably want to search for company names and headlines differently.

```
<field name="headline" type="text" />
<field name="coname" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="false" omitNorms="true" />
```

The above example would allow you to do a search like `&coname:Intel&headline:processor+specifications` and retrieve matches hitting exactly Intel stories.

If you wanted to search a range

*2. Result Fields*

You can defined a standard set of return fields in your [RequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler)

```
<requestHandler name="mumble" class="solr.DisMaxRequestHandler" >
    <str name="fl">
        category,coname,headline
    </str>
</requestHandler>
```

You may also define the desired fields in your query string, using the `fl` parameter.:

```
/select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=coname%3AIn*&start=0&rows=10&fl=coname%2Cid&qt=standard
```

You can also [select ranges](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) in your query terms using the `field:[x TO *]` syntax. If you wanted to select certain ads by their date , you might build a query with

```
ad_date:[20100101 TO 20100201]
```

in your query terms. (There are many ways to search ranges, I'm presenting a method that uses integers instead of Date class.)

Comment: Do you know where I can find a "reference manual" of all classes and attributes for these field-types?

Comment: I typically start on the Solr wiki http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ and the Javadocs for the classes are located here: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/index.html.