# CFSearch + Solr: Ignoring HTML in Searches

Tags: coldfusion, solr, coldfusion-9

I have a problem and Google hasn't helped me much. I'm trying figure out a way to ignore HTML while searching a Solr index in ColdFusion (9).

For example, if I search for `microsoft` and my index contains `Microsoft&copy; makes Windows&reg;` I'm prompted to search for "Microsoft© makes Windows®" rather than showing the actual result.

As you can see below, I'm just passing the string into the criteria property of cfsearch - but again - doing this produces (what I consider to be) a "dirty" result.

```
  <cfsearch
      collection="mycollection"
      criteria="microsoft"
      name="results"
      maxrows="100"
      suggestions="always"
      contexthighlightbegin="<strong>"
      contextHighlightEnd="</strong>"
      contextPassages="3"
      />
```

I've been looking at the documentation for [Solr's query syntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) but I don't see anything that jumps out at me on how to avoid this problem.

Should I look at providing the index a "flat" version of text or is there a way to avoid HTML strings such as `&copy; / &reg; / &trade;`?

I'm open to suggestions.

-- Brian.

Comment: I'm using CF10 which should be using Solr 3.4 according to http://www.corporatezen.com/2013/11/updating-solr-engine-coldfusion/.  I added `<charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>` to `<fieldType name="text">` but the search result still returns HTML.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that might be faced with the same question:

The solution for this question was to use an alternate method of indexing rather than trying to work around the HTML within the index.

Within the database I created a new field called `index_search` and on my insert method within my application I used a regex to omit any special(er) characters: `"[^[:word:].[:space:]-]"`

From there, I passed the `index_search` field to the body of `cfindex` and used the HTML name as the title:

```
  <cfindex
    collection="mycollection"
    action="update"
    body="name_search,html_description"
    title="name_html"
    key="UUID"
    query="data">
```

Using this method produced the expected output when searching for words or phrases close to, or, wrapped in HTML. IE: Searching `microsoft` would lists all results with `Microsoft©` within it.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the Solr field you're using to search is set up with String field type and not with Text (which admits tokenization and other text analysis). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118634/how-to-determine-field-type-for-solr-indexing) for more information about this.

In case it is really a problem of stripping HTML, you'll have to add [HTMLStripCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory) to your field type configuration, which strips HTML tags from the indexed field.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio.

From what you posted, it looks like there is no (relatively) easy way of doing this with ColdFusion + Solr so I think I'm just going to strip out HTML before indexing.

Comment: The only issue with HTMLStripCharFilterFactory or any other charFilter is that these were introduced in Solr 1.4, and CF 9 runs Solr 1.3 by default. Even CF 9.0.1 appears to run a pre-1.4 Solr release. That's not to say that one can't upgrade because one certainly can, only that won't be what is running on CF 9 out of the box.

Comment: @DavidFaber : wow, Solr 1.3 is now ~3.5 years old. That's *a lot* in Solr years :)