# Facing issue while searching on string type field

Tags: solr, solrj

I am facing issue in Solr search.
My schema is as follows

```
<fieldType name="c_text" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
<field name="parentId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="data_s" type="c_text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="email" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="receivedDate" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I am searching on email field. which contains the data in following format
Tarun Nagpal <tarunn@abc.com>

```
//This is working fine
email:*tarun*
```

But following is giving no result

```
email:"Tarun Nagpal"
```

Can you please help, why it is not searching phrase like search on email field.
Search on data_s field is working fine.

Comment: Try searching on `email:"tarun nagpal"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the text field type since you intend to search the tokens:

To be specific for `Tarun Nagpal <tarunn@abc.com>`:

A **string** field will answer `==` equality and wildcard queries like `*un Nagp*`, `*unn@abc.com>` and even more apparently exotic queries.

A **text** field will answer to the tokens `tarun`, `nagpal`, `tarunn` `abc` and `com`.

Other field types implementing N-gram and Soundex can even correct your spelling.

---

See the excellent https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119479/604511