# How to configure SOLR queries in the conf files

Tags: solr

My requirement is simple.

I need to search with the keyword similar to SQL LIKE.

Now the search shows results for "words" rather than checking partial characters.

### Ex:-

- Search query: "test"
- Expected results: "test%" - Which gives "test",    "tested",
  "testing", etc...
- Actual result: "test"

I found many query suggestions for SOLR. But I need to find the exact mechanism to put that on conf xml files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the record: To pass the problem, and due to the restriction of time, I managed to solve the problem by handling it on client side - By putting wild character at the end of search keyword. "test*". But I am looking for the best option available.

Comment: Wouldnt a stemmed field satisfy your example? Its much easier and more powerful than an SQL LIKE, that you can stop thinking in terms in terms of LIKE. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10362591/604511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution is to use wildcard in your search query using an asterisk (*). For example:  `test*`

The more proper solution would be to use stemming to remove common word endings when you index and query the data. In the default schema, the `text_en_splitting` field type would do this for you. Just define your field as text_en_splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building auto-complete?

If so, use `Suggester`.  It's part of Solr, and it does what you're talking about extremely efficiently using either a dictionary file, or a field in your index you've designated.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester